# Raster image preview showing empty layer in geoserver

Tags: geoserver

I have added a raster layer (GeoTIFF) on GeoServer, it is visible up to a certain zoom, but after that, it shows a blank screen, even though on click, it is returning values for RED, GREEN, BLUE, ALPHA band.
[image: blank image]

blank image
[image]

working image

Logs are showing no errors

```
2021-03-24 21:48:30,934 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-03-24 21:48:31,543 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
    Angle = 0.0
    BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    Bbox = SRSEnvelope[344457.52820239705 : 344719.3898535189, 3117493.9743865044 : 3117952.083152021]
    BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
    Buffer = 0
    Clip = null
    CQLFilter = null
    Crs = PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 43N", 
  GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
      SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
  PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","9807"]], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 75.0], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 500000.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","32643"]]
    Elevation = []
    Env = {}
    Exceptions = application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage
    FeatureId = null
    FeatureVersion = null
    Filter = null
    Format = image/jpeg
    FormatOptions = {}
    Get = true
    Height = 769
    Interpolations = []
    Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@bc01a9e8]
    MaxFeatures = null
    Palette = null
    RawKvp = {EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage, FORMAT=image/jpeg, REQUEST=GetMap, SRS=EPSG:32643, BBOX=344457.52820239705,3117493.9743865044,344719.3898535189,3117952.083152021, VERSION=1.1.1, STYLES=, WIDTH=440, SERVICE=WMS, HEIGHT=769, TRANSPARENT=true, LAYERS=tiger:testgarud}
    RemoteOwsType = null
    RemoteOwsURL = null
    Request = GetMap
    RequestCharset = UTF-8
    ScaleMethod = null
    Sld = null
    SldBody = null
    SldVersion = null
    SortBy = null
    SortByArrays = null
    SRS = EPSG:32643
    StartIndex = null
    StyleBody = null
    StyleFormat = sld
    Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=raster]]
    StyleUrl = null
    StyleVersion = null
    Tiled = false
    TilesOrigin = null
    Time = []
    Transparent = true
    ValidateSchema = false
    Version = 1.1.1
    ViewParams = null
    Width = 440
```

Comment: Don't just repost your closed question, please fix the other question. You need to turn up the logging level in GeoServer and look at the log file then

Comment: Hi, I actually checked the log file, it shows normal GetMap requests. I'm not sure if there are any errors in that. :/

Comment: If you have turned up the logging level then your log will contain DEBUG and TRACE level logging that will tell us what is going on - yours doesn't, so you haven't done what I asked.